# How to load a webpage into webview in android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I am trying to make a simple android app that loads a webpage into a `WebView`.

```
package com.example.abhi.molinahealthcare;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Molina_HealthCare extends ActionBarActivity {
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_molina__health_care);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    openURL();
}

private void openURL() {
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    webview.requestFocus();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_molina__health_care, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

ACTIVITY:-

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I was not able to open it. I have the `INTERNET` permission declared in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: have you added `INTERNET` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: YES I HAVE ADDED THE INTERNET PERMISSION ALSO

Comment: i just want to load a webpage on my android application buut not using android browser!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing `webview` object of WebView which you are using in `openURL` method. do it by initializing `webview` instead of `myWebView` in `onCreate`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_molina__health_care);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        ...
```

Comment: such errors the one who tries to figure out the problem usually couldn't notice, for a while I felt like his code is correct